# ActiveMQ on Linux

Tags: linux, apache, activemq-classic

I'm trying to install an application on Linux which requires ACTIVEMQ.
I tried installing activeMQ and re running the application still facing this error

> Cannot instantiate class:
>   org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory [Root exception
>   is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory]

Also in the set up of application the jar for activemq is already present

Linux version Linux 2.6.32

Comment: Maybe this should be moved to unix.stackexchannge?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run activemq directly from bin where as i was suppose to go in 64 bit and then do that :)